# Xamarin.Realm issue - runtime skipping lines

Tags: xamarin, realm

Consider the following code:

[image]

At runtime, the first breakpoint is literally **skipped**. My `GetInstance()` is never invoked, and the variable `realm` is always null.  No matter what code exists above the yellow line below, none of it is ever invoked, and any variables declared are simply their default values.

To fix this, simply changing the `if` line to invoke `realm.All<UserCredential>().ToList().FirstOr....` fixes the issue.  The first breakpoint is called, the variable `realm` is correctly initialized, etc.

This hasn't been an issue until recently; iqueryables have been working fine for the past few weeks.  There's only one thing recently changed:  I added a directory named "Engines" to the root of this .csproj (which is a pcl), and it made a very subtle change to the .csproj:

`<UseMSBuildEngine>true</UseMSBuildEngine>` was added.

I'm suspicious I broke something by adding the "Engines" directory.  With this knowledge, I changed my "Engines" directory name, renamed the files in it, and removed this added property from the .csproj.  This didn't make any difference.

And yes, I've cleaned, reset iOS simulator, cleaned derived data, restarted Xamarin Studio, restarted osx, banged my head on the table, etc.

I'm very nervous about the stability of Xamarin (or Realm?) with this.  If one little adding of a directory can silently compromise my entire project by **skipping** lines of code, what hope have we?

Comment: Which IDE and version are you using and what Xamarin version/channel are you on?

Comment: We're on the latest of the Xamarin Studio Community stable channel (6.3 build 863)

Comment: And using the latest of Realm, 1.2.0

Comment: In my experience Xamarin Studio occasionally has issues with iOS, particularly with breakpoints and especially when you're placing breakpoints in other projects being referenced. However, you can usually resolve such issues by deleting everything in your bin and obj folders in your project and all projects being referenced and then rebuilding.

Comment: We've experienced the same.  We certainly did clear our bin and obj, and even tried exterminating xCode's derived data (although I'm not certain Xamarin builds causes xCode to write to it).  It was definitely caused by the issue I mentioned in the answer.  Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.  Xamarin wasn't actually completely removing the "Engines" folder from the disk, just the reference to it in the .csproj.  After manually deleting the actual directory called "Engines" as well, it seems to be working properly.

I hope this helps anybody who runs into this issue in the future!